# NodeJS: how to install dependencies for all modules (packages)?

Tags: node.js, module, npm, package, installation

I have project (NodeJS):

```
p
--modules
----m1
------foo.js
------package.json
----m2
------bar.js
------package.json
package.json
```

Each package.json has own dependences. Is it possible to install all dependencies by one command from root folder "p"? Something like this:

```
npm install --all
```

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install
```

This will install all dependencies. Nothing extra needed just run inside 'p'.

Comment: I would consider removing dependencies and reinstalling then.  Also I just noticed you have `------package.json package.json` if you actually have that in your code in that lay out it could be an issue. Also may be worth trying `npm update`

Comment: Updated file structure.